# Why does my Google Chrome extension only open 25 tabs out of many more?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a piece of code here that just doesn't want to work right as a Chrome Extension.

As far as I can tell, everything works perfectly, except it stops opening pages around tab 25, no matter how many tabs should be opened. I checked the code and it attempts to open every single link properly, but in reality it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
for (x = 0; x<55; x++){
   window.open();
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to break this down a bit more.  Does the initial `.each()` loop get called the appropriate number of times?  Where specifically is your code failing?  Is the value of `openedTabs` always as expected, the full number?  If it truly is failing on `window.open()` I suspect you're hitting some sort of safety/security limit imposed by Chrome.

Comment: The initial '.each' loop is only called once, activating for each url on the entire page it finds. The value of 'openedTabs' is always correct. And I don't know of any safety limit, but I would really like to get around it, haha

Comment: Sorry, I meant how many times is the code within that loop ran, but if `openedTabs` is correct, that answers the question.  Just for kicks, if you have a really simple loop that does nothing but open 50 windows, does it stop at 23 or so?  Is it always 23?  Have you tried putting a `sleep` in there?

Comment: I've tried the sleep command with no luck, and its actually 25 windows. I'll try the script now.

Comment: Maybe a `setInterval()` at 300ms, and loop through that way?  Clearly, this would be quite a hack for production code, but may help us figure out if Chrome is cutting you off for security reasons, or if there is something else going on, such as bad parameters or URL.  I don't suppose there is anything in your debugging console?

Comment: I just did `for (x = 0; x<55; x++){window.open();}` and it opened 25 windows. -.-

Comment: @Wyko, I can't confirm, but it certainly sounds to me like a, *"Google_Bob: Hey Joe, we should limit this.  What's the biggest number of windows someone would ever want to open?  Google_Joe:  Oh, I think 25 will do!"* kind of a problem.

Comment: I suggest putting that latest line of test code as the code in your post, since it is a simple, reproducible form of your question.

Comment: That seems really odd... maybe you're right though. That pretty much ends this entire expention though, which sucks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7903/discussion-between-wyko-and-brad)

Answer (score 3):

There is an [intentional upper bound](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/content/renderer/render_view_impl.cc&exact_package=chromium&q=kMaximumNumberOfUnacknowledgedPopups&type=cs&l=290) of 25 on `window.open` calls. See Chromium bugs [2632](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=2632) and [3382](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3382) for background, but in brief, the idea is to prevent denial-of-service (both UI-wise and memory-wise) attacks from pages that open popups indefinitely.

Extension APIs like `chrome.tabs.create` (as PAEz's answer suggests) are not subject to these APIs, since extensions are privileged access already.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something to do with a popup blocker or what Brad said.
Its easy enough to deal with tho, just use the tabs api....

```
for (x = 0; x<55; x++){
   chrome.tabs.create({url:"nowhere"+x});
}
```

...55 tiny tabs ;)