# Chrome Extension create new tab loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome Extension that loops through URLs and opens new tabs (about 12).  This is not distributed through the Web store and only has a few users who want this specific functionality.  Recently, it has stopped opening all the tabs and only opens 3 or 4 (this doesn't seem consistent -- sometimes it opens 3, sometimes it opens 4).  The relevant code is as follows:

```
for (key in mySites.open){
    if (motorclearSites.open[key]==false){
        chrome.tabs.create({'url': mySites.loginPages[key]});
    } else {
        chrome.tabs.update(mySites.open[key], {url: mySites.loginPages[key]});
    }
}
```

By way of explanation, mySites.open[key] is boolean and tells me if that tab is already open (e.g. mySites.open['google'] = false).  If it isn't, then I open it.  If it is, then I update it.  mySites.loginPages[key] is the URL of the page that I want to have open in the new tab (e.g. mySites.loginPages['google'] = 'http://www.google.com');

Anyway, if I remove chrome.tabs.create and just give it a console.log, it goes all the way through the loop and shows me all the URLs I want to open.  If I just run this as is, however, it gets through either the first three or the first four and does not open any other tabs.

Any ideas on what I might do to fix this?

Comment: How many tabs you have open (already)? As for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347121/why-does-my-google-chrome-extension-only-open-25-tabs-out-of-many-more there is a hard limit of 25.

Comment: Yeah this happens regardless of the number of tabs - I've experimented with just one open originally and still I can only open 3 or 4 new ones.

Comment: hey, am having the same problem, is there some change in the chrome API regarding allowing the extension to open fixed number of tabs?

Comment: Cody, the problem was that the popup JS stops running as SOON as the tab switches - on chrome.tabs.create, set "active":"false" before your URL - this will open the tabs without switching to them and that should fix it.

Comment: PS this was a change in the API - because it WAS working before.

Comment: @timmyc I think you hit the issue (as far as I see it as well, in Chrome 34 (Mac)), but I'd update your suggestion to use `"active":false` (boolean `false` instead of the string `"false"`).  Worked for me.